# How to check whether dedicated cache worker role is available or not?

Tags: azure

Check availability of dedicated cache worker role, before putting data.

DataCache dc = new DataCache("MarginCache");
dc.Put("test",test);

It throws exception if cache role is not available.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by handling the [DataCacheException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.applicationserver.caching.datacacheexception.aspx). For instance:

```
DataCache cache = null;

try
{
   cache = new DataCache("MyCache");
}
catch (DataCacheException cacheError)
{
   // Handle exception: couldn't create DataCache object
}

try
{
   cache.Put("test",test);
}
catch (DataCacheException cacheError)
{
   // Handle exception: couldn't store object in cache
}
```

See [Exception Handling Overview (Windows Server AppFabric Caching)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff637738%28v=azure.10%29.aspx) for a list of properties you can inspect on this exception and [Common Exceptions (Windows Server AppFabric Caching)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff637716%28v=azure.10%29.aspx) for a list of common errors you should be able to handle, including Timeout and RetryLater.